# How do you push function calls onto an array without calling them in Node JS for using Q?

Tags: arrays, node.js, dynamic, promise, q

I'm looking to create an array of functions to call dynamically, which will be later used in the Q.all([]) promise call.

For example;

```
 //data is previously generated

 var promiseArray = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){     
   promiseArray.push(functionCall(data[i]))
 }
 Q.all(promiseArray).then(function(){
      //Do something 
 })
```

How would I push to the array without calling the function until the Q.all statement? I don't want to call it in the for loop as it will not catch any errors and I can't process the response further.

EDIT:

So to clarify my problem (as I don't think I was as clear as I should have been), here is a solution for a static data length of say 3;

```
//data is previously generated
var data = [12432432,4324322392,433324323];

//Each function call can happen in parallel or series as its an external POST to an API
//I'm not bothered about speed for this application (as its low throughput) and can wait a few seconds for each
// response
//FunctionCall returns a promise

functionCall(data[0]).then(function(){
    //Log success / failure to mongo
});
functionCall(data[1]).then(function(){
    //Log success / failure to mongo
});
functionCall(data[2]).then(function(){
    //Log success / failure to mongo
});

//OR
functionCall(data[0]).then(function(){
    //Log success/failure to mongo
    functionCall(data[1]).then(function(){
        //Log success/failure to mongo
        functionCall(data[2]).then(function(){
            //Log success/failure to mongo
        });
    });
});
```

But I wont know the length of data until runtime

Comment: Uh, `Q.all` does take an array of promises, not of functions, so you *need* to call them?

Comment: Basically I want to be able to create an array of functions to call using Q.all([]), without calling them when adding them to the array. Otherwise I'll call them when I add them and also call them in Q.all([])

Comment: Yes, you do want to call them immediately. `Q.all` will not call them. I don't get why your first snippet wouldn't work. Your argument "*I don't want to call it in the for loop as it will not catch any errors and I can't process the response further.*" is flawed, you can easily catch errors and process the results by chaining `then`.

Comment: @aaaidan i have updated my answer please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to call `functionCall` for an array of items, and have Q.all resolve once all the promises returned by `functionCall` have *completed* regardless if they resolve or reject - if you don't care about the results (as you don't seem to in your code) simply handle the rejection in the promise you push - i.e.

```
var promiseArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    promiseArray.push(functionCall(data[i]).then(function(result) {
        // log success
        return logToMongoFunction(result);
    }, function(error) {
        // log failure
        return logToMongoFunction(error);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // catch and ignore any error thrown in either logToMongoFunction above
        return;
    }));
}
Q.all(promiseArray).then(function () {
    //Do something 
});
```

> Note: the above can be simplified to

```
Q.all(data.map(function (item) {
    return functionCall(item).then(function(result) {
        // log success
        return logToMongoFunction(result);
    }, function(error) {
        // log failure
        return logToMongoFunction(error);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // catch and ignore any error thrown in either logToMongoFunction above
        return;
    });
})).then(function() {
    //Do something 
});
```

---

> the edited question suggests you can perform the actions in series also - in series it would be

```
data.reduce(function(promise, item) {
    return promise.then(function() {
        return functionCall(item).then(function(result) {
            // log success
            return logToMongoFunction(result);
        }, function(error) {
            // log failure
            return logToMongoFunction(error);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            // catch and ignore any error thrown in either logToMongoFunction above
            return;
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
    // all done
});
```

instead of `Promise.resolve()` you could use whatever `Q` has as an equivalent that creates a resolved promise

`logToMongoFunction` would log to mongo and needs to return a promise **if** you need to wait for that to finish before processing the next data item. If you do not need to wait for the mongo logging to complete then there's no need for that function to return a promise

Comment: what if the functionCall got some database operations? for example array  of 10000 length wont this code trigger all the 10000 requests together? i think there should be a queue and these loops should be controlled

Comment: What if nobody invented pants. We'd all be wearing dresses.

Answer (score 0):

i will recommend using Promise.mapSeries or async library for this because its very easy to catch errors. One more thing looping using a for loop doesnt seems to be good approach if you have database calls in the callback because that might flush the calls to the database and node.js can have memory issues or node.js wont be able to entertain any other request because it will be busy entertaining the request in the for loop. so its always good to run loop serially or limit the numer of parallel executions at a time.

please see example below

```
  This will run Array serially one at a time when 1st one completes execution next will be called

  async.eachOfSeries(data, function(dataInstance, key, next) {
    functionCall(dataInstance).then(function(){
        next();
    }).catch(funtion(err){
        next(err);
    })
  }, function() {
        //iteration completed
  });
```

OR

```
 async.eachOfSeries(data, function(dataInstance, key, next) {
    functionCall(dataInstance, function(err , result){
        if(err)
          {
            console.log(err);
            next(err);
          }
          else
            next();
    });
  }, function() {
        //iteration completed
  });
```

Comment: Here promise and callbacks are mixed. It would be cleaner to use either one of them.

Comment: `async` + `Promise` should not be used together

Comment: @JaromandaX why not? can you please explain in detail. Beacause i am using promises in async without any problems. Please explain in detail or share some link so i can read

Comment: @JaromandaX i have used it and never faced a problem. Can you share some link where i can aslo read this? i just want to know if am doing wrong

Comment: One of the things you're doing wrong is that when a function throws, it will be called again (go try figure why). Mixing promises with callback code is error-prone and unnecessarily complex. It *can* work, but it's not a good idea.